# Is the application of the multigrid method correct?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations, multigrid

We consider the boundary problem \begin{align*}-&y''(x)=0 \ \ \text{ for } \ x\in \Omega:=(0,\pi) \\ &y(0)=y(\pi)=0\end{align*} Let's pick the grid size $n=5$.

I want to apply the 2-grid method.

We get the linear system \begin{equation*}A_hu_h=f_h, \ \ \ A_h:=\frac{1}{h^2}\begin{bmatrix}2 & -1 & 0 & 0 \\ -1 & 2 & -1& 0 \\ 0 & -1& 2 & -1 \\ 0 & 0& -1 & 2\end{bmatrix}=\frac{25}{\pi^2}\begin{bmatrix}2 & -1 & 0 & 0 \\ -1 & 2 & -1& 0 \\ 0 & -1& 2 & -1 \\ 0 & 0& -1 & 2\end{bmatrix}, \ \ f_h:=\begin{bmatrix}0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 0\end{bmatrix}\end{equation*}

We apply twice the damped Jacobi method with the relaxation factor $\omega=\frac{2}{3}$.

We have the matrix $J = I-\frac{h^2}2 A_h=\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 & 0 &0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 1\end{bmatrix}-\begin{bmatrix}1 & -\frac{1}{2} & 0 & 0 \\ -\frac{1}{2} & 1 & -\frac{1}{2}& 0 \\ 0 & -\frac{1}{2}& 1 & -\frac{1}{2} \\ 0 & 0& -\frac{1}{2} & 1\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}0 & \frac{1}{2} & 0 & 0 \\ \frac{1}{2} & 0 & \frac{1}{2}& 0 \\ 0 & \frac{1}{2}& 0 & \frac{1}{2} \\ 0 & 0& \frac{1}{2} & 0\end{bmatrix}$.

For $\omega=\frac{2}{3}$ we get the following damped version: 
$J(\omega) = (1-\omega)I + \omega J= \frac{1}{3}I + \frac{2}{3}J=\begin{bmatrix}\frac{1}{3} & 0 & 0 &0 \\ 0 & \frac{1}{3} & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{3} & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{3}\end{bmatrix}+\begin{bmatrix}0 & \frac{1}{3} & 0 & 0 \\ \frac{1}{3} & 0 & \frac{1}{3}& 0 \\ 0 & \frac{1}{3}& 0 & \frac{1}{3} \\ 0 & 0& \frac{1}{3} & 0\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}\frac{1}{3} & \frac{1}{3} & 0 & 0 \\ \frac{1}{3} & \frac{1}{3} & \frac{1}{3}& 0 \\ 0 & \frac{1}{3}& \frac{1}{3} & \frac{1}{3} \\ 0 & 0& \frac{1}{3} & \frac{1}{3}\end{bmatrix}$

The damped Jacobi method is then: 
$$v^{(i+1)} = J(\omega)v^{(i)} + \frac\omega 2{h^2}f=\begin{bmatrix}\frac{1}{3} & \frac{1}{3} & 0 & 0 \\ \frac{1}{3} & \frac{1}{3} & \frac{1}{3}& 0 \\ 0 & \frac{1}{3}& \frac{1}{3} & \frac{1}{3} \\ 0 & 0& \frac{1}{3} & \frac{1}{3}\end{bmatrix}v^{(i)}$$

Let's consider the starting vector $v^{(0)}=\begin{bmatrix}1\\ 1\\ 1\\ 1\end{bmatrix}$.

Then we get the following: 
$$v^{(1)} = J(\omega)v^{(0)} + \frac\omega 2{h^2}f=\begin{bmatrix}\frac{1}{3} & \frac{1}{3} & 0 & 0 \\ \frac{1}{3} & \frac{1}{3} & \frac{1}{3}& 0 \\ 0 & \frac{1}{3}& \frac{1}{3} & \frac{1}{3} \\ 0 & 0& \frac{1}{3} & \frac{1}{3}\end{bmatrix}v^{(0)}=\begin{bmatrix}\frac{1}{3} & \frac{1}{3} & 0 & 0 \\ \frac{1}{3} & \frac{1}{3} & \frac{1}{3}& 0 \\ 0 & \frac{1}{3}& \frac{1}{3} & \frac{1}{3} \\ 0 & 0& \frac{1}{3} & \frac{1}{3}\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}1\\ 1\\ 1\\ 1\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}\frac{2}{3}\\ 1\\ 1\\ \frac{2}{3}\end{bmatrix}$$ 
$$v^{(2)} = J(\omega)v^{(1)} + \frac\omega 2{h^2}f=\begin{bmatrix}\frac{1}{3} & \frac{1}{3} & 0 & 0 \\ \frac{1}{3} & \frac{1}{3} & \frac{1}{3}& 0 \\ 0 & \frac{1}{3}& \frac{1}{3} & \frac{1}{3} \\ 0 & 0& \frac{1}{3} & \frac{1}{3}\end{bmatrix}v^{(1)}=\begin{bmatrix}\frac{1}{3} & \frac{1}{3} & 0 & 0 \\ \frac{1}{3} & \frac{1}{3} & \frac{1}{3}& 0 \\ 0 & \frac{1}{3}& \frac{1}{3} & \frac{1}{3} \\ 0 & 0& \frac{1}{3} & \frac{1}{3}\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}\frac{2}{3}\\ 1\\ 1\\ \frac{2}{3}\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}\frac{5}{9}\\ \frac{8}{9}\\ \frac{8}{9}\\ \frac{5}{9}\end{bmatrix}$$

The residual is then $$r_h:=f_h-A_hv^{(2)}=-\frac{25}{\pi^2}\begin{bmatrix}2 & -1 & 0 & 0 \\ -1 & 2 & -1& 0 \\ 0 & -1& 2 & -1 \\ 0 & 0& -1 & 2\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}\frac{5}{9}\\ \frac{8}{9}\\ \frac{8}{9}\\ \frac{5}{9}\end{bmatrix}=-\frac{25}{\pi^2}\begin{bmatrix}\frac{2}{9}\\ -\frac{1}{3}\\ \frac{1}{3}\\ \frac{2}{9}\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}-\frac{50}{9\pi^2}\\ \frac{25}{3\pi^2}\\ -\frac{25}{3\pi^2}\\ -\frac{50}{9\pi^2}\end{bmatrix}$$

We go to the coarser grid: 
$$r_{2h}=I_h^{2h}r_h=\frac{1}{4}\begin{bmatrix}1 & 2 & 1 & 0  \\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 2\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}-\frac{50}{9\pi^2}\\ \frac{25}{3\pi^2}\\ -\frac{25}{3\pi^2}\\ -\frac{50}{9\pi^2}\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix} \frac{25}{36\pi^2}\\ -\frac{175}{36\pi^2}\end{bmatrix}$$

Our new problem on the coarse grid is then the following: 
$$A_{2h}e_{2h}=-r_{2h}$$ where \begin{align*}A_{2h}&=I_h^{2h}A_hI_{2h}^h=\frac{1}{4}\begin{bmatrix}1 & 2 & 1 & 0  \\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 2\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}\frac{50}{\pi^2} & -\frac{25}{\pi^2} & 0 & 0 \\ -\frac{25}{\pi^2} & \frac{50}{\pi^2} & -\frac{25}{\pi^2} & 0 \\ 0 & -\frac{25}{\pi^2}& \frac{50}{\pi^2} & -\frac{25}{\pi^2} \\ 0 & 0& -\frac{25}{\pi^2} & \frac{50}{\pi^2}\end{bmatrix}\frac{1}{2}\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 \\ 2 & 0 \\ 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 2\end{bmatrix}\\ & =\frac{1}{8}\begin{bmatrix}1 & 2 & 1 & 0  \\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 2\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}\frac{50}{\pi^2} & -\frac{25}{\pi^2} & 0 & 0 \\ -\frac{25}{\pi^2} & \frac{50}{\pi^2} & -\frac{25}{\pi^2} & 0 \\ 0 & -\frac{25}{\pi^2}& \frac{50}{\pi^2} & -\frac{25}{\pi^2} \\ 0 & 0& -\frac{25}{\pi^2} & \frac{50}{\pi^2}\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 \\ 2 & 0 \\ 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 2\end{bmatrix}\\ & =\frac{1}{8}\begin{bmatrix} 0& \frac{50}{\pi^2}& 0& -\frac{25}{\pi^2}\\ 0& -\frac{25}{\pi^2}& 0& \frac{75}{\pi^2}\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 \\ 2 & 0 \\ 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 2\end{bmatrix}\\ &= \begin{bmatrix} \frac{100}{8\pi^2}& -\frac{50}{8\pi^2}\\ -\frac{50}{8\pi^2}& \frac{150}{8\pi^2}\end{bmatrix}=  \begin{bmatrix} \frac{25}{2\pi^2}& -\frac{25}{4\pi^2}\\ -\frac{25}{4\pi^2}& \frac{75}{4\pi^2}\end{bmatrix}\end{align*} Now we apply again twice the damped Jacobi, right? Which starting vector do we use?

Is everythig correct so far?

Then we calculate $v^{(2)}-I_{2h}^he_{2h}$ where $e_{2h}$ is the solution of the last Jacobi method, or not?

Is this then the result, I mean the last approximation of the solution of the initial value problem?

Comment: You can use a direct method on the coarse grid now to get the solution (just solve that 2x2 system accurately), then prolong (multiply the transpose of the interpolation matrix) the solution to the fine grid, adding this prolongation to the initial guess on the fine grid you have finished a two-grid cycle.

Comment: After having calculated $e_{2h}$ do we calculate $v^{(2)}+I_{2h}^he_{2h}$ or $v^{(2)}-I_{2h}^he_{2h}$ ? And after that Osborne the 2-grid method finished or do we have to apply again the damped Jacobi? @ShuhaoCao

Comment: By the definition of your coarse grid problem, $e_{2h}$ approximates $v- u_h$ on the coarse grid, so you should do $v - Ie_{2h}$. You can add another damped Jacobi which is called post-smoothing as well.

Comment: Knowing that $e_{2h}$ approximates $v-v_h$ how does it follow that we have to do $v-Ie_{2h}$ ? Could you explain this further to me? @ShuhaoCao

Comment: Let's say $v$ is the iterate, and $u_h$ solves the linear system exactly, then $v - (v-u_h)$ will get you the solution. Now you don't have this exactly, instead you have an approximation $e_{2h}$ to $v-u_h$ on the coarse grid. You add it back to compensate the low frequency error.

Comment: Ah ok! I see!! After having updated the solution, i.e. after having calculated $v-Ie_{2h}$ do we have to check if the error, i.e. the difference between the approximation and the exact solution, is small enough and if not we apply again twice the damped Jacobi method? @ShuhaoCao

Comment: After applying once the 2-grid method with the V-cycle we get a better approximation that the initial once. Do we stop here? Or do we have to apply that again? Or do we apply that just once at the V-cycle? @ShuhaoCao

Comment: Exactly, when the error is not within a tolerance you set, just apply the two-grid procedure again.

Comment: Ah ok! The V-cycle of the 2-grid method is the following or not? We apply twice the damped Jacobi method, then we calculate the residue. Then we restrict the residue on the coarse grid. Then we solve $A_{2h}e_{2h}=-r_{2h}$. Then we interpolate the error on the fine grid. Then we update the approxaimation of the solution. $$$$ Is this the V-cycle of the 2-grid method? @ShuhaoCao

Comment: V-cycle needs more levels ($h$, $2h$, $4h$, etc). If you apply the same procedure again with this new iterate as your initial value, it is two-grid.

Comment: I got stuck right now... At the 2-grid we have just two levels, or not'? One fine and one coarse. According to the V-cycle we start from the fine grid, we go to the coarse grid and then again to the fine grid. Or haven't I understood correctly the idea? @ShuhaoCao